# Accessing External Database in /data/data

Tags: android, sqlite, process, root, su

I need to access a database in /data/data/com.XXXX/databases/XXX.db (Not My app's Database).
How can i using root privileges access this external database.

```
String sqlQuery = ...
try {
            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su sqlite3 /data/data/com.xxxxxxx/databases/xxxx.db "+ sqlQuery );
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

But this code isn't working (I had the app which uses this db closed when i ran my app)

Note:

Nothing is wrong with the Sql Query code (I tried copying the db then editing it and it worked fine)
I Don't want to copy the db to sd card , i want to edit it while its in data/data/com.xxx...

Comment: The only way I see is to copy the db from the foreign app to your /data/data/... path

Comment: Keep in mind that people aren't stupid and most certainly they encrypted their db (at least, WhatsApp and similar apps do)

Comment: the reason i don't want to copy it is because when i tried copying it to sd , editing it then returning it back. The program that has the Database stated that the database is corrupted .

Comment: Obviously. They perform some kind of integrity check, to prevent hackers from doing what you are trying to do.

Comment: The database isn't encrypted i succeeded in editing it (I opened the Database using SQLlite on my pc)

Comment: That's embarassing. Shame on them.

Comment: There are apps on the market who succeeded in achieving what i'm trying to do. The Apps that succeeded edited the database without copying it.

Comment: Even in Whatsapp the database in data/data/com.whatsapp isn't Encypted.

Comment: WhatsApp db **is** encrypted, for security reasons.

Comment: The db found in sdcard/whatsapp/ is encrypted, but not the one found in data/data/com.whastapp/databases . See for your self

Comment: I stopped using WhatsApp when Zuckerberg (FaceBook = CIA) bought it.